# Как спуститься по тегу вниз в selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

Мне нужно достать текст из новостей в вк. Сначала я нахожу у каждой новости id, затем по Xpath тег  с id этой новости.
Мой запрос выглядит так:

```
IWebElement el = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"wpt-"+e+"\"]/div[1]"));
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(el.FindElement(By.ClassName("wall_post_text")));
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Не получилось");
                }
```

Вот как выглядит этот тег.

```
<div id="wpt-30316056_6798776" class="wall_post_cont _wall_post_cont">
```

Срабатывает блок catch, то есть поиск по классу не происходит.
Вопрос заключается в том, как можно спуститься к следующему тегу div, который лежит дальше. Вот к этому:

```
<div class="wall_post_text">Ну наконец-то достойные соперники для сборной России. Тут-то без шансов</div>
```

Эта строка `IWebElement el = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"wpt-"+e+"\"]/div[1]"));` срабатывает, и из нее можно получить запись из новости, НО помимо текста берется еще первый комментарий, время и пр., чего быть не должно. Поэтому и возникает вопрос, можно ли как-то получить именно тот блок с классом `wall_post_text`, потому что из тега нужно достать ЭТО **Ну наконец-то достойные соперники для сборной России. Тут-то без шансов.**

Или же нужно как-то по-другому доставать текст и другие данные из новостей?

Вот кусок элемента с данными div-ами.

```
<div id="wpt-30316056_6798776" class="wall_post_cont _wall_post_cont">
<div class="wall_post_text">**Ну наконец-то достойные соперники для сборной России. Тут-то без шансов**(ЭТО НАДО ДОСТАТЬ)
</div>
<div class="page_post_sized_thumbs  clear_fix" style="width: 510px; height: 377px;">
<a href="/video-30316056_456348854?list=664d8677d3b8f0346c" data-video="-30316056_456348854" data-list="664d8677d3b8f0346c" data-duration="28" aria-label="Видео .webm длительностью 28 секунд " onclick="return showInlineVideo(&quot;-30316056_456348854&quot;, &quot;664d8677d3b8f0346c&quot;, {&quot;autoplay&quot;:1,&quot;addParams&quot;:{&quot;post_id&quot;:&quot;-30316056_6798776&quot;}}, event, this);" style="width: 510px; height: 378px;background-image: url(https://i.mycdn.me/getVideoPreview?id=1686791588469&amp;idx=7&amp;type=39&amp;tkn=Fm2dUiSrTGdZsc-7f84tW_SaMOE&amp;fn=vid_x);" class="page_post_thumb_wrap image_cover  page_post_thumb_video page_video_autoplayable page_post_thumb_last_column page_post_thumb_last_row">
<div class="page_post_video_play_inline">
</div>
<div class="video_thumb_label"><span class="video_thumb_label_item"></span><span class="video_thumb_label_item">0:28</span>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="media_desc post_video_desc">
  <a class="lnk" id="post_media_lnk-30316056_6798776_0" onclick="return showVideo(&quot;-30316056_456348854&quot;, &quot;664d8677d3b8f0346c&quot;, {&quot;autoplay&quot;:1,&quot;queue&quot;:1,&quot;addParams&quot;:{&quot;post_id&quot;:&quot;-30316056_6798776&quot;}}, event, this);" href="/video-30316056_456348854?list=664d8677d3b8f0346c" data-video="-30316056_456348854" data-list="664d8677d3b8f0346c" data-duration="28" aria-label="Видео .webm длительностью 28 секунд ">
    <div class="a post_video_title">.webm
</div>
<div class="post_video_views_count">111<span class="num_delim"> </span>432 просмотра
</div>
  </a>
</div></div>
```

Comment: `/div[1]` - забудьте про это. HTML зачастую очень динамичен. что будете делать, если нужный вам элемент вдруг сместится? Авторы рекламу всунут или что-то еще. Только классы или id, забудьте про индексы... По поводу новостей - а вы уверены, что вам нужно вовсе знать их id? Блок новостей обычно расположен в одном "контейнере", например это таблица, или `div` внутри которого список всех новостей. То есть вам достаточно взять этот "главный контейнер" и из него забрать все внутренние элементы, вот уже будет у вас список всех новостей. А сам вопрос, лично я не понял, вы же получили то, что надо, не?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ` вы уверены, что вам нужно вовсе знать их id?`, действительно, надо попробовать от главного контейнера. Я получил не совсем то, что хотел, потому что вместе с текстом новости, я также получаю первый комментарий, поэтому нужно спуститься ниже.

Comment: Я не вижу в предоставленном вами коде комментарий. Поэтому извините, но без данных, вашу задачу, мы решить вряд ли сможем. Вот сейчас вы в вопросе просите `wall_post_text`, мы видим, что вы его получаете `By.ClassName("wall_post_text")`, все, в наших глазах, как видите, вы получили все нужное. Пожалуйста, задавайте вопросы так, чтоб мы могли их воспроизвести у себя, делайте минимальный, самодостаточный пример!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, отредактировал. Найти от общего контейнера не получилось.

Comment: Тогда я вас не понимаю. Вы всячески игнорируете строку `Console.WriteLine(el.FindElement(By.ClassName("wall_post_text")));`, которой должны были получить нужный текст. Если это она вам дает время, комментарии и прочее - то этого быть не может, ибо в ней только один текст, ну либо вы опять нам не весь HTML даете...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я же написал, что срабатывает блок catch, а сам блок try не работает и выдает ошибку Unhandled exception. `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".wall_post_text"}`. Текст новости и прочее выдает самая первая строка `IWebElement el = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"wpt-"+e+"\"]/div[1]"));`. Вот от прочего мне и надо избавиться

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129362/discussion-between-pavel-garbuzov-and-evgeniyz).